# Rate of Return with Random Variables

Tags: probability, finance

Problem from Sheldon Ross's Elementary Introduction to Finance (Exercise 4.28):

For an initial investment of 100, an investment yields returns of $X_i$ at the end of period $i$ for $i = 1,2$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent normal random variables with mean $60$ and variance $25$. What is the probability that the rate of return on this investment is greater than $10$ percent?

In the book he defines the rate of return as the rate so that the present value is equal to the initial payment

What I have so far:

$$0 = -100 + \frac{X_1}{1+r} + \frac{X_2}{(1+r)^2}$$

$$0 = \frac{-X_1 + \sqrt{X_1^2 +400X_2}}{2X_2}$$
What I had in mind was to solve this should give an answer for $\frac{1}{1+r}$. Then by adding 1 and taking the reciprocal I could make an expression for $r$ and then use the random variable's distribution to solve for $r > 0.1$. But it's looking pretty tough to do it this way if it's even possible. Is this approach this correct or if there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Sorry, it accidentally submitted before I finished and then I couldn't save my edits because the server was down

Comment: You seemed to have interpreted the problem wrong. The investment doesn't generate cash flows of $X_1$ and $X_2$. It generates returns of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Assuming the returns are in percent, the cash flows are either $100(1+X_1/100)$ and $100(1+X_1/100)(1+X_2/100)$ or $100e^{X_1/100}$ and $100e^{X_1/100+X_2/100}$ depending on how the book defines returns. I think your calculation will be easier in the second definition.

Comment: I was following an example done in the textbook which resembles this question. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/mDwUv9m) is the example.

Comment: The example you link to deals with $X_1$ and $X_2$ as known constants.  The question here has them being normal random variables.  So the mean and variance have to come into it somehow....

Comment: @TickaJules Do you have any suggestions on how I should start it out?

Comment: Here's how I would progress:  Set $X_1=60+5z_1$ and $X_2=60+5z_2$ for std normals $z_1$ and $z_2$.  Resolve your first equation to get a quadratic in $r$ (with $z_1$ and $z_2$ in the equation).  Of the two roots, the minus one is <100% so ignore.  Take the + root.  You need to find the range of $z_1$ and $z_2$ that make $r>10$%.  I end up with a line cutting through the $(z_1,z_2)$ plane equal to $11z_1+10z_2 \ge -10$.  You'd then need to integrate the bivariate normal "above" that line, unless I made a mistake somewhere.....

Comment: Got it, I'll try that out!

Comment: sorry should have been "one root is <-100% so ignore" in my previous comment....